# Google Custom Search date range

Tags: date-range, google-custom-search

I've been trying to set a daterange for the results I get on Google Custom Search but couldn't figure out how yet.
My url, so far, looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=MY_OTHER_KEY&q=bigdata&alt=json&fields=queries(request,nextPage),items(title,link,snippet)&cr=&start=1
```

I'm trying to get, for example, the results inside the range of 01/01/2014 to 02/01/2014. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: After a little bit of poking around, Google seems to only give an option for a maximum date. *([All parameters](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list))* Would you be willing to do something software-side to filter out the too recent entries? I haven't done any tests, but it seems as Google only allows [boolean operators](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#booleanOperators) for two parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I'll have to work around it somehow. Could you provide me with the link from where you got this info?

Comment: There are two links in that comment (*"all parameters"* and *"boolean operators"*).

Comment: My bad, didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: It has been answered here:
[Date range search using Google Custom Search API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406933/date-range-search-using-google-custom-search-api)