# Date range search using Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-custom-search, google-image-search

I am using the Google Custom Search API to search for images. My implementation is using Java, and this is how I build my search string:

```
URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?"
                + "v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&userip=INSERT-USER-IP");
```

How would I modify the URL to limit search results, for example, to: `2014-08-15` and `2014-09-31`?

Answer (score 7):

You can specify a date range using the `sort` parameter. For your example, you would add this to your query string: `sort=date:r:20140815:20140931`.

This is documented at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#page_dates

Also if you use Google's Java API you can use the `Query` class and its  `setSort()` method rather than building the URL by hand.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way is to put this into query itself. Query parameter contains 'after' flag which can be used like:

```
https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=<api_key>&
cx=<search_engine_id>&
q="<your_search_word> after:<YYYY-MM-DD>"
```

Comment: Interesting. You can also use `before:` One thing to note is that the `before:` parameter **is not inclusive**, while the `sort=date:r` **is inclusive**.

Comment: I tested both method and the result is almost the same. I could not find this solution on  the docs, so I think the sort range is preferable.